# Extract only files with specific extension via bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, zip, unzip

For a first time I need to create an `.sh` for do something. My aim is to unzip a lot of zip folders, so I've wrote the script below:

```
for zipfiles in /downloads/*.zip; do unzip $zipfiles; done
```

I can unzip all but I noticed that there are some files with the same name and typing `y` I can ultimate the process.

There is a way to extract only files with a specific extension, like `.docx`, instead of the entire zip folder? I'm absolutely sure that there aren't `.docx` with the same name.

Comment: Sidenote: [variables should almost always be quoted in Bash to avoid word splitting and globbing](/a/10067297/4518341), so: `unzip "$zipfiles"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a pattern:

```
for zipfiles in /downloads/*.zip; do unzip "$zipfiles" '*.docx'; done
```

Tested to work with `UnZip 6.00`.

You can also specify the `-x` option to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, it can be useful for your purpose.

```
for zipfiles in /downloads/*.zip; do unzip -xo "$zipfiles" '*.docx' ; done
```

by this option overwrite files WITHOUT prompting.